# Delete a view in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view

I've a script in js to delete a view.
It's correctly deleted but i go to the failureMethod

```
    function deleteView(){
view.deleteObject();
view.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessdelview,OnFailuredelview);
function OnSuccessdelview(){
    console.log("temporary view successfully deleted");
}
function OnFailuredelview(){
    console.log("error during delete of temporary view");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs since `view.update();` is called for deleted view, the specified line have to be removed.

### How to delete a List View using JSOM

```
function deleteView(listTitle,viewTitle,success,error)
{ 
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
   view.deleteObject();
   context.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
}
```

**Usage**

```
deleteView('Documents','View to delete',
   function() {
      console.log('List View has been deleted');   
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   });
```